# Why has my reputation decreased while nothing changed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

My reputation on Stack Overflow was lessened by 105 points today. 
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you violate the rules and regulation given by SO

Answer (score 7):

Since You have violated the voting rules and regulation of Stackoverflow

Take a look at this

[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to prevent someone spammingly upvote everything he sees on SO. Suppose someone wants to get more reputation he can simply apply for another account and build enough reputation, then upvote every answer of main account. That way the main account can get thousands of reputation that way. Just to point out that reputation building is **SLOW** process :)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

> Vote reversal as a result of voting fraud will also return lost or
>   gained reputation.